# PHP Cannot Install OpenSSL, Need to encrypt file with password

Tags: php, openssl

I've been requested from a customer to create a script that encrypts files with a password, and I wrote a script using OpenSSL
as follow:

```
$this->salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10);
        $this->cryptoKey = openssl_pbkdf2($key, $this->salt, $this->cryptoKeyLength, $this->iterations, 
          $this->algorithm);
        $this->iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher));
```

The issue is, the customer doesn't have openssl and the hosting does not provide an user with enough rights to install php-openssl using yum i get I don't have enough privileges.
The website has https tho.

Is there another lib to use?
is there a way to use openssl as a class and include is as .php?
is there another function like this possibly native?
is there a weaker way to do the same possibly natively?
thanks
Would it be possible to install php on another machine and pass the request as a proxy and return the output, would it be a smart way out?

Comment: phpseclib has pure PHP implementations for encryption, as far as I know